# Oracle Procedure Takes long time to run but the straight sql runs quick

Tags: oracle, performance, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a block of sql that runs pretty smooth outside the procedure. The moment I put the sql block in the procedure to return the ref_cursor, the procedure takes quite a bit of long time to execute the ref_cursor.

With help from DBAs, we implemented DB profile and it worked great to speed up the procedure but then any minor change in that particular procedure make it go haywire. I am not sure what the problem.. I am running out of options. How should I go about troubleshooting this particular weird issue?

Thank you in advance.

Edit.. here is the query

```
with query_ownership as (SELECT leeo.legal_entity_id,
                           leeo.parent_le_id,
                           SUM(leeo.effective_ownership) ownership_percent
                      FROM data_ownership leeo
                     WHERE leeo.start_date <=
                           to_date('12/31/2012','mm/dd/yyyy')
                       AND ((leeo.end_date < &lvTaxYearDate and leeo.end_date > &lvTaxYearBeginDate)
                           to_date('12/31/2012','mm/dd/yyyy') OR
                           leeo.end_date IS NULL)
                       and leeo.stock_type in ('E')
                     GROUP BY leeo.legal_entity_id, leeo.parent_le_id
                    HAVING SUM(leeo.effective_ownership) > 0
),
query_branches as ( SELECT b.branch_id       as legal_entity_id,
                           b.legal_entity_id as perent_le_id,
                           1.00              as ownership_percent
                      FROM company_branches b
                     WHERE b.tax_year = 2012),
child_query as (select * from query_ownership
                    UNION
           select * from query_branches),
parent_query as (select * from query_ownership
                    UNION
           select * from query_branches),                                       
inner_query as (SELECT rownum                        as sortcode,
                   -level                        as lvl,
                   child_query.parent_le_id,
                   child_query.legal_entity_id,
                   child_query.ownership_percent
              FROM child_query
             START WITH child_query.legal_entity_id = 'AB1203'
            CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR child_query.legal_entity_id =
                        child_query.parent_le_id
                   AND child_query.ownership_percent >= 0.01
                   and level = 0
            UNION
            SELECT rownum as sortcode,
                   level - 1 as lvl,
                   parent_query.parent_le_id,
                   parent_query.legal_entity_id,
                   parent_query.ownership_percent
              FROM parent_query
             START WITH parent_query.legal_entity_id = 'AB1203'
            CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
             PRIOR parent_query.parent_le_id =
                        parent_query.legal_entity_id
                   AND parent_query.ownership_percent >= 0.01)
                  ,ownership_heirarchy as (
               SELECT max(inner_query.sortcode) as sortcode,
           max(inner_query.lvl) as lvl,
           inner_query.parent_le_id,
           inner_query.legal_entity_id,
           inner_query.ownership_percent from inner_query
     GROUP BY inner_query.parent_le_id,
              inner_query.legal_entity_id,
              inner_query.ownership_percent
              )
              ,goldList as (
SELECT lem2.legal_entity_id from ownership_heirarchy,
   company_entity_year lem1,
   company_entity_year lem2
WHERE ownership_heirarchy.parent_le_id = lem2.legal_entity_id
AND lem2.tax_year = 2012

AND ownership_heirarchy.legal_entity_id = lem1.legal_entity_id
AND lem1.tax_year = 2012
AND lem1.legal_entity_type <> 'EXT'
AND lem1.non_legal_entity_flag is null
AND lem2.legal_entity_type <> 'EXT'
AND lem2.non_legal_entity_flag is null
and TRIM(lem2.alt_tax_type) is null
and UPPER(lem2.tax_type) in ('DC', 'DPS', 'TXN')
),
fulllist as (
         select * from goldList
        union
         select gc.parent_le_id from company_entity_year e,       consolidation_group gc 
where e.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID = 'AB1203' and e.tax_year = 2012
and e.TAX_CONSOLIDATION_GRP = gc.group_id
        union
         select e.leid from vdst_entity e where e.TAX_YEAR = 2012
         and e.ALT_TAX_TYPE in (3,8)
         and e.LEID = 'AB1203'
) 

  select  distinct dc.dcn_id      as dcnId,
         dc.dcn_name    as dcnName,
         dy.dcn_year_id dcnYearId,
         ty.tax_year_id taxYearId,
         ty.tax_year    taxYear
    from company_dcn dc, company_dcn_year dy, company_tax_year ty
   where dc.dcn_id = dy.dcn_id
     and dy.year_id = ty.tax_year_id
     and ty.tax_year = 2012
     and dc.leid in (
         select * from fulllist
                     );
```

Comment: The problem clearly is on line 17 of your stored procedure.

Comment: Updated the question to include the query in question.

Comment: Sounds like there may be a different execution plan for the query with literals ("smooth outside the procedure") and bind variables (in PL/SQL).

Comment: Updates: I ended up creating indexes for some of the mat views I was using in the procedure and the performance has been pretty decent. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that statistics are up-to-date by running `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS` for each table involved in the query. Next, obtain the plan for the query with different parameter values - it's entirely possible that a change in the parameters may make the plan better or worse. Given that you're showing us no information about the query, the procedure, and the tables involved there's no way to be more specific.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what part of the execution plan is causing problems.  There are several ways to do this:

1. **Use `DBMS_XPLAN` to find a good and bad plan.**  Use `explain plan for ...` and `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` to find the good plan in your session.  Use `dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'some sql_id')` to find the bad plan.  Compare the plans and look for differences.  This can be very difficult because you can't usually tell which parts of the execution plan are slow.  If you're lucky there will be only one difference and then obviously that difference is the problem.
2. **Use `DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR` to find what part of the plan is bad.**  Run the bad query and use SQL Monitoring to find out which operation in the execution plan is bad.  The report shows which operations take the longest, and which cardinality estimates are off by the most.  Focus on the slow parts, and the first steps of the plan with a huge cardinality difference between estimated and actual.
3. **Look at profile hints to find out how Oracle fixes the bad plan.**  Profiles are a collection of hints that help nudge the optimizer into making the correct decisions.  Those hints might tell you what the problem is.  For example, if one of the hints is `OPT_ESTIMATE(JOIN (A B) SCALE_ROWS=100)`, the profile is telling the optimizer to increase the cardinality estimate by 100X.  You may be able to recreate that same affect by either including that hint in the query or by creating and locking fake table statistics.  Use [this process](http://kerryosborne.oracle-guy.com/2009/04/oracle-sql-profiles/) from Kerry Osborne to find the profile hints.

Either way, this process can be difficult and time-consuming.  Try to shrink the query as much as possible.  Tuning a 97 line query can be almost impossible some times.  It's possible there is only one root problem, but that problem changes so much of the execution plan that it looks like there are a dozen problems.

These steps only help you identify the problem.  Fixing it may be a whole other question and answer.